# NextJS "Can't resolve" error attempting to import PostCSS file

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

In a NextJS project that uses TailwindCSS, I have a global css file, `index.css` and I'm trying to import another `file.pcss` into the global css file. But, NextJS can't seem to find `file.pcss`, produces the error below:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'file.pcss' in '/home/chris/repo/styles'
```

`index.css` has:

```css
@import 'file.pcss';
```

Not sure  why this is happening because Next + Tailwind should support PostCSS without issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Figured it out!**

When I converted both files to `.scss` files. Everything started working again.

**Result:**

global css file renamed to: `index.scss`

```css
@import 'file.scss';
```

pcss file renamed to: `file.scss`

Solution came from: https://github.com/vercel/next-plugins/issues/565#issuecomment-561086895